# Same content-sections on multiple pages in wordpress - what alternative is best to do this?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

First of all, thanks to you who are trying to help me by reading my question :)
My question is this:

I have this theme I'm trying to complete. But there's one thing thats bugging me... If you look at this image:

[This is the image I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja6qY.png)

I want to include the section "Meriter" on multiple pages in wordpress. The admin should be able to change the images in this section together with the text under each image, but I only want the admin to be able to change this in one place...

What is the best way to do this? Custom post types? I really don't know, and it feels like I'm missing something here. How would you do this?

Much thanks for reading this and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Custom Post Types UI together with Advanced Custom Fields. Did the trick...